# How are certain technical words used in British English?

Tags: british-english, terminology

I have noticed that many terms in software come from American English, as the US was responsible for much software engineering terminology. I want to know how Britishers use these terms in these specific contexts.

1. How do Brits say "refactoring code" (which means to decompose code into more easily workable parts)? Do they say "refactorizing"? Americans use  *factor*  as a verb; Britishers don't.

   Do Brits say "Database indices" instead of "Database indexes"?

   Is this correct British English: "We attended the entertainment  *programme*  after we corrected issues with our software *program*  ?"

Comment: Can you explain that comment about Brits not using *factor* as a verb? Speaking as a Brit, I think it's plain wrong, so I'm curious to see on what basis you make that claim.

Comment: I don't know for 100% sure, but as far as my experience goes "factorize" is British and never used in US; similarly "factor" is American.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Britons say *refactoring code* rather than *refactorising code* and certainly not *refactorizing code*, to the extent they say such a phrase at all.
2. Both are used.
3. "The entertainment programme" is slightly unusual as a phrase in this context; the issue is not with *program(me)*. The following is certainly correct: "I have written a computer program to suggest a schedule of television programmes to record".

Answer (score 2):

1, factor is a verb as a specific maths term in BE. BE tends to avoid "izing" endings - like AE burglarize.

2, Indices is correct if you are writing a textbooks, but indexes is used.

3, Program = software, Programme = TV. No good reason, it's just one of those things

Comment: "Indexes" are used for databases specifically, hence the question - I know the general usage. "Program" came from the US during the start of the computer era, whereas "-mme" was already well established.